# DEM - flat 'peaks' - truncated output

Tags: dem, export

I am working with a DEM downloaded from the national park service. The peaks appear like completely white areas, I assumed it was just a subtle change in elevation.

I exported a high resolution (4096 x 4096) region to .png format and brought it into world machine. The resulting model has completely flat peaks.

Could the DEM be bad? Do I need to export to a difference format? Is there something I've missed?

[image: DEM in QGIS]

[image: Flat model in world machine]

Comment: Is your style actually using the full range of values? What do you see if you use the blue "i" icon on different areas?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If the source of elevations were contours being triangulated, flat peaks  are "normal", I don't think you can do much about it

Comment: The styles appear to only relate to symbols. Toggling the property widget doesn't provide me with any more information that the coordinates at the bottom. I don't seem to be able to get an elevation off of the DEM.

Comment: I am using QGIS and I'm new to it.

Comment: Yea but they all wouldn't be the same elevation, the very top of the peak might be flat, but the height of it would be correct relative to the rest. My image doesn't show it, but there are lower peaks that are shades of grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used world machine before but I would guess that your conversion to png is mutating the image data.

A DEM cell value can be any number but once you changed it to png I would guess you are then constraining it to a max range of 0-255 colours so what you see in your second image is a representation of the shades of grey of your first image.

Recreate a png with the DEM stretched to min/max and you might see those flat peaks disappear but again all you will be creating is a 3d representation of changes in colour and not actual elevation.  Personally I wouldn't try changing the format of the DEM as you could introduce errors.

Comment: Even though the layer properties said 'stretch to min max', it appears to have been clamped clipped.